# Как сделать ссылку на пост в теме на StackOverflow

Tags: поддержка

Если мне необходимо гиперссылку, чтобы сразу указывала на пост (или комментарий к посту) пользователя размещённого на StackOverflow, как это сделать?

Comment: На пост - нажми "поделиться" под ним. На коммент - никак.

Comment: @Akina "На коммент - никак." Я с Вами не согласен :)

Comment: @UModeL Каждый может ошибаться. Если Вы скажете, как сослаться на комментарий - придётся признать, что в данном вопросе ошибся именно я...

Comment: @Akina, если на время нажать, то прямо на комментарий попадаешь.

Answer (score 7):

- На вопрос — *поделиться* + <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
- На ответ — *поделиться* + <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
- На комментарий — ПКМ по *времени комментария* + копировать адрес ссылки

Comment: Я и у ссылки поделиться адрес коприрую - так удобнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy те же яица. Если 1 рука лежит на клавиатуре - кнопка, если просто мышь - мышью

Comment: Вряд ли ты ссылку "поделиться" нажимаешь с клавиатуры, так что на мыши рука есть ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy я имею ввиду если используется только 1 рука и она лежит на мыши